# React get size of parent element within ResponsiveReactGridLayout

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-grid-layout

I'm trying to render a dashboard using `ResponsiveReactGridLayout` and my code in the functional component is as follows:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState(latestCoins);
  const [coin, setCoin] = useState(curCoin);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCoins().then((data) => setCoins(data));
  }, []);
  return (
    <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
      onResize={(e) => console.log(e)}
      className="layout"
      layouts={layouts}
      rowHeight={100}
      breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
      cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
    >
     
      <div key="candlestick" className="home-card" ref={canvasRef}>
        {console.log(canvasRef)}
        //Trying to use canvasRef.current.width and height but getting an error: Property 'width' does not exist on type 'never'
        <Candlestick coin={coin} width={600} height={400} />
      </div>
    </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
  );
};
```

My Candlestick component does return a ChartCanvas object from `react-stockcharts`, which needs a width and height (without which it does not take up the entire space of the div)

How can I get the height and width from the div?

I've tried using the `useRef()` hook, but it always seems to have current as null.

Could I get some help?

Comment: Please add UseRef() code as well with the description. Most probably u might use it out side of react scope of updating values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Property 'width' does not exist on type 'never'

This is actually a TypeScript error.  It means that TypeScript doesn't know what the type of the `.current` property is supposed to be.  Therefore it doesn't know that `.current` has properties `.width` and `.height` and it prevents you from accessing them.  You need to tell TypeScript that this is a ref to a `div`.

An `HTMLDivElement` *doesn't* actually have `.width` and `.height`, but you can use `.clientWidth` or `.offsetWidth` instead.

```
const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

---

> I've tried using the useRef() hook, but it always seems to have current as null.

The `ResponsiveReactGridLayout` component is setting its own refs on its children, so your `ref={canvasRef}` gets overwritten.

The simplest way around this is to add another layer of nesting.  The `ResponsiveReactGridLayout` will set a ref on the outermost `div`, but you can add another `div` inside of it with a ref that you control.  Make sure that it fills up the entire height.

Note that the `.current` property might still be `null` on the first render.  You can use a default value, as suggested by @PushpikaWan, or you can delay rendering the chart until you have an actual width.

```
<ResponsiveReactGridLayout /*...props...*/ >
    <div key="candlestick" className="box">
        <div ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
            {canvasRef.current ? (
                <Candlestick
                    data={data}
                    width={canvasRef.current.clientWidth}
                    height={canvasRef.current.offsetHeight}
                />
            ) : null}
        </div>
    </div>
    /*...other children...*/
</ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
```

---

I needed to add an explicit `width` on the grid layout in order to get this to work.  I'm not sure if you are doing this part already, but you can use the `WidthProvider` as explained [in the docs](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#providing-grid-width).

```
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from 'react-grid-layout';

const ResponsiveReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-element-size-edjq6?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Linda! Adding another div with a width on it seems to work. Going to try and align it now.

Answer (score 0):

You might get it as undefined with initial loading please use this optional statement there

```
canvasRef?.current?.width
```

If you have any default value u can use **Nullish coalescing** as well with the default value

```
canvasRef?.current?.width?? default_value
```

then it will be like below

```
 <Candlestick coin={coin} width={canvasRef?.current?.width?? default_width} height={canvasRef?.current?.height ?? default_Height} />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Still saw the same error of ```Property 'width' does not exist on type 'never'.```

Comment: @ShubhankarAgrawal that's a TypeScript error.  You need to use `const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);`

Comment: @LindaPaiste, thanks for correcting me on that, but I still see canvasRef.current is always null.

Comment: Is it *always* `null`, or always `null` on just the first render?  I think it will be `null` at first and then get a value.  But tbh you aren't making use of the `onResize` function which is probably the better method.  I might go update my answer.

Comment: @LindaPaiste, it's always null no matter how many times I refresh. Apologies I'm new to ReactJS

Comment: @ShubhankarAgrawal I think what's happening is that the `react-grid-layout` package is setting its own ref on the child div and overriding your ref, but I have to look into it more.